# cannot install rmagick with Windows 10 / Ruby 2.x / rails 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rmagick

I am trying to install Rmagick on a Win 10 machine for developing in the Ruby 2/rails 3 environment.

I've tried following various suggestions from different posts but have not had a success.

My current configuration is

- Windows 10 64 bit laptop.
- Installed ImageMagick-6.9.8-9-Q8-x86-dll.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8
- Environment variable CLASSPATH `C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8\lib C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8\include`
- Env Variable CPATH C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8
- Env Variable LIBRARY_PATH C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8\lib
- NOTE - the above env variables are NOT in the system variables section they are in the user variables.
- Command run in the rails project folder root: `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0' --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8\lib --with-opt-include=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8\include`

Response/error:

```
C:\Users\cmendella\Documents\Projects\intranet>gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0' --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8\lib --with-opt-include=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8\include
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-lib=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8\lib --with-opt-include=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8\include'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/ext/RMagick
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170606-10484-1nvf2n8.rb extconf.rb --with-opt-lib=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8\lib --with-opt-include=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8\include
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:141:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version (Errno::ENOENT)
        from extconf.rb:141:in `configure_compile_options'
        from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
        from extconf.rb:548:in `new'
        from extconf.rb:548:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out
```

Comment: is there a reason why you are not using rails 4.x or 5.x? I am sure you will run into a lot of issues with rails 3.

Comment: I'm on a team that grew a number of inter-related projects on 3.x. We are in the process of mapping out a plan to migrate to 5.x but that will take a couple of months at least.